# Laravel: reading available months and years from timestamp to populate a <SELECT>

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a films table which a timestamps column CREATED_AT. THe format is:

```
name            created_at
Pocahontas      2016-12-28 22:09:24
```

I know how to select films from the table added this current month

```
    $year_month_film = DB::table('films')
        ->select('films.*')
        ->whereMonth('films.created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->month)
        ->orderBy('films.created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

But now I want to let the user to select dynamically a list of films added on any month of any year (see the image):

[image: Selected all films from december 2016]

I built two  in the HTML view in order to select dynamically the films added any month of any year.

```
<div class="pull-right">
            <select>
              <option value="all" selected>Months</option>
              <option value="January">January</option>
              <option value="February">February</option>
              <option value="March">March</option>
              ...
            </select>              
            <select>
              <option value="all" selected>Years</option>
              <option value="2011">2011</option>
              <option value="2014">2014</option>
              <option value="2016">2016</option>
              ...
            </select> 
        </div>
```

The questions are:

1. I did not add films every month and every year, therefore I need to know which months and which years (independent from each other) exists in the database by reading the column "created_at". And then pass to the view. But I have not idea how to do it using Carbon.
2. How could I grab the selected month and year in the , pass then to the controller and make a dynamic search instead just the current month that I posted at the beginning?

**EDIT:**

Just to update to somebody who may be useful:
I have removed the duplicated months by adding a line to the code apported by Yohanan Baruchel and the code looks now like that:

```
$available_years_with_months = [];

        $all_year_and_months = DB::table('films')
           ->select('*')
           ->orderBy('films.created_at', 'desc')
           ->get()->each(function($film) use (&$available_years_with_months) {
             $date = Carbon::parse($film->created_at);
             $year = $date->format('Y');
             $month = $date->format('F');
             $available_years_with_months[$year][] = $month;
            $available_years_with_months[$year] = array_unique($available_years_with_months[$year]);

           });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get only a list of months that actually have movies you can use the next lines that I wrote for you:

```
$available_years_with_months = [];

$all_year_and_months = DB::table('films')
       ->select('*')
       ->get()->each(function($film) use (&$available_years_with_months) {
         $date = Carbon::parse($film->created_at);
         $year = $date->format('Y');
         $month = $date->format('F');
         $available_years_with_months[$year][] = $month;
       });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution brings me a list of months like: August august august november november november...). for each of the months available in the database without identifying the year it belongs to. I need to pass a couple of parameters to the data base in order ro get the films addes in one specific month. So I need a list like: august 2011, november 2011, august 2012, november 2013, etc). So I could just pass one item to the database and get the films from august 2011 or november 2013. Other thing would be just eliminated the duplicated entrances.

Answer (score 0):

Springtf is for change number range to two.

```
$year_month_film = DB::table('films')
    ->select('*')
    ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', sprintf("%02d",Carbon::now()->month))
    ->orderBy('films', 'desc')
    ->get();
```